# Tab structure working for desktop but not working for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a tab structure, its working fine for desktop views..

But not working for mobile devices..

Please suggest any changes or script to resolve this issue.

My Code Snippet:

```
....
....    
<div class="tabs">
  <!--for desktop-->
  <div class="tab-button-outer">
    <ul id="tab-button">
      <li><a href="#tab01">Billing Details</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab02">Shipping Details</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab03">Order Review</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab04">Payment Method</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!--for mobile-->
  <div class="tab-select-outer">
    <select id="tab-select">
      <li><a href="#tab01">Billing Details</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab02">Shipping Details</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab03">Order Review</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab04">Payment Method</a></li>
    </select>
  </div>
  ....
  ....
 </div>
....
....
```

Comment: What parts fails on mobile?

Comment: @MaartenDev which i have highllighted as "for mobile" in comment

Comment: Should they be hidden for mobile? What css are you using?

Comment: @AnjaliPatil Try a more responsive approach, like this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't put li tags inside a select tag. 
In the select tag, you can only put option tags.
consider this:

```
<select>
    <option><a href="#tab01">Billing Details</a></option>
      <option><a href="#tab02">Shipping Details</a></option>
      <option><a href="#tab03">Order Review</a></option>
      <option><a href="#tab04">Payment Method</a></option>
</select>
```

Also note that it will not link you to another page or change the domain name, but you can do it manually, and catch the selected option with `onchange` listener in javascript.

Checkout the onchange docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange

Comment: You cannot put `<a>` inside `<option>` either! ;)